# Can I use an automatic pool cleaner designed for an above ground pool, in an inground pool?

Tags: cleaning, pool

I found a new [Dirt Devil Pool Boy automatic pool cleaner](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003IBRT3Y) for an above ground pool. However, I have an in ground pool, and I'm wondering what the difference is? Does it have to do with traction (getting up the slope in an inground pool)?

Comment: I'd ask the manufacture.